# Can forcing people to not lock their Windows be taken as a security problem?

Tags: device-locking, windows-11

Today I have finally resolved [one of the most irritating (at least for me) features](https://onezeronull.com/2022/12/13/help-my-computer-goes-to-sleep-1-minute-after-i-lock-it/) of Windows 11. That is fact that my computer goes to sleep 60 seconds or so after I lock it even though I have set it to be always on, if it is wall-powered.

Because I am living completely alone and I have about a mile to my closest neighbour, before I found out the above situation, I was simply keeping my computer always unlocked, as it is suggested in [the article](https://onezeronull.com/2022/12/13/help-my-computer-goes-to-sleep-1-minute-after-i-lock-it/).

The last sentence is something that sticks deeply in my heart:

> That’s all about Microsoft understanding of security. Force people to keep there computers unlocked to prevent some hidden, stupid Windows 11 feature.

I'd like to ask someone with bigger expertise than mine to provide a feedback to the above sentence. Can it be true? Can we consider a serious security problem the fact that Microsoft is hiding mentioned feature and thus encourage at least certain people from locking their computer?

Comment: this is probably being cynical, but in my unqualified opinion, you no longer "own" the windows os instance running on your device .. so why would one expect to have any say in how much power it consumes?! people leaving their sessions unlocked and on is obviously an unintended consequence .. i propose we explore the possibility of charging the user per session duration to fix the problem `(:`

Comment: Aren't you basically asking if bad/unexpected usability can result in security problems since users somehow work around it? Sure, this is not new and not specific to Windows or Microsoft either. This can be observed in many situations, like broken password policies etc.

Comment: The question is based on a logic error, and therefore unanswerable. Or at least, it is possible for contrary answers and tangential answers to all be correct. Forcing the power off does not "encourage people to not lock their computers" and you therefore cannot make a security conclusion. This reads more like a rant than an answerable question. Yes, forcing people to not lock their computers can be a security issue, but that's not what is happening here at all.

Comment: @schroeder I'd say that _forcing people to not lock their computers can be a security issue, **and is exactly** what is happening here at all_. Before installing Windows 11 and learning that it goes to sleep when I lock my computer, there wasn't a single issue in past 10 years that I left my computer not locked. But you of course has a right to disagree and close this question. Thank you for your opinion.

Comment: No one is being forced to not lock their computers. That's not an opinion. That's the heart of the logic error in the question.

Comment: @schroeder: Of course forcing power off when locked encourages people to not lock computers that they need to continue running.  I doubt the summary "forcing power off when locked" is exactly accurate from a technical standpoint, but if users (owners) perceive it that way, then avoiding the lock is a completely predictable consequence.

Comment: @trejder: Leaving the computer unlocked may be the easiest workaround, but you've already recognized that it's a bad workaround.  So solve the issue properly, either by changing the unattended-sleep settings as shown in your link, or by configuring the PC to be available for remote access, or by installing a system service that cancels transitions to sleep.  And then you may use the screen lock normally.

Comment: Yes, it can be considered a security issue. "Security at the expense of usability is at the expense of security". You make a user use a 16-character random password, they'll write it on a sticky note. You make a user turn their computer off whenever it's locked, they won't lock it.